# How can I run ZooKeeper's zkCli.sh commands from Bash?

Tags: bash, apache-zookeeper

Is it possible to run a zkCli.sh command, like `ls /` or `get /`, from Bash directly without going inside the ZooKeeper shell?

I am using ZooKeeper version 3.4.6-1569965.

For example, something like this:

```
$ ./zkCli.sh get /
```

I am able to do this only after connecting to the ZooKeeper shell and then running `get /` from there, like below:

```
$ ./zkCli.sh
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:AuthFailed type:None path:null
JLine support is enabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] get /
[]
```

Comment: Have you tried  `./zkCli.sh -cmd "get /"`

Comment: where can I find zkcli on my host ?

Answer (score 19):

zkCli.sh has supported process commands since version 3.4.7.

See *[ZK Shell/Cli not processing commands](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1897)*

Such as:

```
./zkCli.sh -server xxxxx:2181 get /test
```

[zkcli](https://github.com/go-zkcli/zkcli), a [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29) command-line interface for ZooKeeper is also a simple solution.

```
zkcli --servers srv-1,srv-2,srv-3 create /demo_only some_value
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Bash without going inside directly. However, the only disadvantage to this is that you have to make sure that your zk command/syntax is correct.

This would work:

```
#! /bin/bash
zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181 <<EOF
get /testnode
quit
EOF
```

But this won't:

```
#! /bin/bash
zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181 <<EOF
gt /testnode
quit
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

I can obtain HBase Master address, for example, with the following syntax:

`zkCli.sh -server myserver get /hbase/master` 
If it does not work, this other will:

```
zkCli.sh -server myserver <<EOF
get /hbase/master
quit
EOF
```